# Improve speed and memory use in the construction of linear combinations of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, memory

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`, for instance

```
list1=RandomReal[{-10,10},500]
list2=RandomReal[{-10,10},600]
```

and two sets of coefficients,

```
coeffs1={-1,-0.618,0.618}
coeffs2={0.618,-0.618,-1}
```

From these, I would like to generate a nested list of elements where

```
newList[[i,1]]=coeffs1[[i]] list1 + coeffs2[[i]] list2[[1]]
newList[[i,2]]=coeffs1[[i]] list1 + coeffs2[[i]] list2[[2]]
...
newList[[i,-1]]=coeffs1[[i]] list1 + coeffs2[[i]] list2[[-1]]
```

That is, I want every linear combination of one element from `list1` and one from `list2` and grouped first by the index of the coefficient in the linear combination `coeffs1` and `coeffs2`, then by the index of the element in the combination from `list2`. The most straightforward way to do this would be:

```
newList=Table[coeffs1[[i]] list1[[j]]+coeffs2[[i]] list2[[k]],{i,1,3},{j,1,Length@list1},{k,1,Length@list2}]
```

But this is far too slow (it can be sped up significantly with `Compile`, but its scaling behaviour for large lists still makes it undesirable). Alternatively, I could use some list manipulation:

```
meshgrid = {ConstantArray[list1, Length@list2], Transpose@ConstantArray[list2, Length@list1]};
newList=Transpose/@Table[coeffs1[[ii]] meshgrid[[1]] + coeffs2[[ii]] meshgrid[[2]], {ii,3}]
```

which is significantly faster, but still slower than I'd like and probably requires much more memory than the first method because of `meshgrid`. The length of `list1` and `list2` is going to be around 1500, and the code will be part of a loop that is run many thousands of times, so I would like the code to be as fast as possible (while secondarily minimizing the memory used) in the construction of `newList`. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I'm mostly interested in the case `Length[list1]==Length[list2]`, if this can be taken advantage of in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 500];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 600];
coeffs1 = {-1., -0.618, 0.618};
coeffs2 = {0.618, -0.618, -1.};

First@RepeatedTiming[
  newList = 
    Table[coeffs1[[i]] list1[[j]] + coeffs2[[i]] list2[[k]], {i, 1, 
      3}, {j, 1, Length@list1}, {k, 1, Length@list2}];
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  meshgrid = {ConstantArray[list1, Length@list2], 
    Transpose@ConstantArray[list2, Length@list1]}; 
  newList2 = 
   Transpose /@ 
    Table[coeffs1[[ii]] meshgrid[[1]] + 
      coeffs2[[ii]] meshgrid[[2]], {ii, 3}];
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  newList3 = MapThread[
     Outer[Plus, ##] &,
     {
      KroneckerProduct[coeffs1, list1],
      KroneckerProduct[coeffs2, list2]
      }
     ];
  ]

Max[Abs[newList - newList2]]
Max[Abs[newList - newList3]]
```

> 0.90022
>
> 0.0013152
>
> 0.000390233
>
> 0.
>
> 0.

Answer (score 2):

First we create the data:

```
n = 500;
list1 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, n];
list2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, n];
coeffs1 = {-1, -0.618, 0.618};
coeffs2 = {0.618, -0.618, -1};
```

Then we create the first and second part of the result and add them:

```
t1 = (ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list1) # & /@ coeffs1;
t2 = (ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list2 // Transpose) # & /@ coeffs2;

res = t1 + t2;
```

To check we take your lengthy expression and compare the result to the above:

```
res1 = Table[ 
   coeffs1[[i]] list1[[j]] + coeffs2[[i]] list2[[k]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 
    1, Length@list1}, {k, 1, Length@list2}];

res == res1

(* True*)
```